# Proof that $R\hat{\mu}$ is multivariate normal

Tags: probability, normal-distribution

> Let $\bf{X_1},\dots,\bf{X_n}$ be a sample of i.i.d multivariate normal, where
>   each $\bf{X_i}\sim N_p(\bf{\mu},\bf{\Sigma})$ where $\bf{\mu}$ and
>   $\bf{\Sigma}$ are the vector of means and the matrix of covariance.
>   Find the distribution of $\bf{R}\bf{\hat{\mu}}$ where $\bf{R_{1\times
>  p}}$ is a vector of constants and $\hat{\bf{\mu}}$ is the maximum
>   likelihood estimator of $\bf{\mu}$.

I will not put things in bold. What I did is

I know that $\hat{\mu}=\frac{1}{n}\sum X_i$. Let $Y=R\hat{\mu}$ so
$$M_Y(t)=E[\exp(t'Y)]=E[\exp(t'(\frac{1}{n}R(X_1+\dots+X_n))]$$
where $t_{1\times p}$.

$$M_Y(t)=E[\exp(t'\frac{1}{n}RX_1)]\dots E[\exp(t'\frac{1}{n}RX_n)]$$
$$=E[\exp(\frac{1}{n}(R't)'X_1]\dots E[\exp(\frac{1}{n}(R't)'X_n]$$ 
$$=M_{X_1}(\frac{1}{n}R't)\dots M_{X_n}(\frac{1}{n}R't)$$

$$=\exp(\frac{1}{n}(R't)'\mu+\frac{1}{2}\frac{1}{n}(R't)'\Sigma (R't)\frac{1}{n})\dots \exp(\frac{1}{n}(R't)'\mu+\frac{1}{2}\frac{1}{n}(R't)'\Sigma (R't)\frac{1}{n})$$

$$=\exp(t'R\mu+\frac{1}{n}(\frac{1}{2}t'R\Sigma R't))\sim N_p(R\mu,\frac{R\Sigma R'}{n})$$

Is it right? I need to check any assumption about $R\Sigma R'$ to ensure that it is multivariate normal?

Comment: I think that's correct. $\hat\mu \sim N(\mu, \Sigma/n)$ so $R\hat\mu \sim N(R\mu, R\Sigma R^T/n)$ should follow without additional assumption.

Comment: $R$ is a constant row vector? So this is a dot product and gives you a univariate random variable. You may use the similar trick to show this well-known fact that the linear combinations of multivariate normal is still multivariate (univariate) normal.